# AngularJs: Bind ui-select from Json and filter table

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Using AngularJS 1.3.4.

I have a html table that is being populated from an web api where I make an http request to get that data and populate my html table. My example json is as below:

```
{
    id: 1,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Rein",
    status: 'available'
},
{
    id: 2,
    firstName: "David",
    lastName: "Gumry",
     status: 'not available'
}
```

Now I have a dropdown below the table, and I am using ui-select for it. I want to populate this dropdown based on the status in my json. For example in my json above I have 2 status available and not available. I want my dropdown to have these values. After I populate my dropdown, I want to filter my table based on the dropdown value that is selected. I have my dropdown as:

```
  <ui-select tagging ng-model="selected" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...">{{$select.selected.value}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="val in values | filter: $select.search track by val.value">
        <div ng-bind="val.value | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>        
</ui-select>
```

I have created my jsfiddle at: 
https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/wfL1374x/

I am not sure how can I bind the results from json to my DDL and filter my table.

Comment: The link to your jsfiddle is broken

Comment: @jbrown I have fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few issues that needed handling including redundant use of ng-app and ng-controller.  Also, it seems as though ui-select works best using the ControllerAs syntax which is a preferred approach in general.

After these changes and others (too many to list), here's the working code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.select'])

  .controller("PeopleCtrl", function($http) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.people = [];
    vm.isLoaded = false;
    vm.values = [];

    vm.loadPeople = function() {
      // *** I had to comment this out as it is not allowed in the SO Code Snippet but is fine for your code
      //$http({
      //  method: 'POST',
      //  url: '/echo/json/',
      //  data: mockDataForThisTest

      //}).then(function(response, status) {
      //  console.log(response.data);
      //  vm.people = response.data;
      //});
      vm.people = [{
          id: 1,
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Rein",
          status: 'available'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          firstName: "David",
          lastName: "Gumry",
          status: 'not available'
        }
      ];

      vm.values = [...new Set(vm.people.map(obj => ({
        value: obj.status
      })))];
    };

    vm.selected = {
      key: null,
      value: null
    };

    var mockDataForThisTest = "json=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify([{
        id: 1,
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Rein",
        status: 'available'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        firstName: "David",
        lastName: "Gumry",
        status: 'not available'
      }
    ]));
  })
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl as ctrl">
    <br>
    <p> Click <a ng-click="ctrl.loadPeople()">here</a> to load data.</p>

    <h2>Data</h2>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="person in ctrl.people | filter: {status: ctrl.selected.value} : true">
            <td>{{person.id}}</td>
            <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{person.status}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br><br>

    <div width="50px">
      <ui-select tagging ng-model="ctrl.selected" theme="bootstrap">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...">{{$select.selected.value}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="val in ctrl.values | filter: $select.search track by val.value">
          <div ng-bind="val.value | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank for this. I had mentioned that the dropdown needs to be populated from the json itself, not the hardcoded values. I had created with hardcoded values as I dont know how to populate that from json. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: I’m not sure what more you are looking for. You have an $http call to get the data. What else are you needing?

Comment: The ui-select is bind to repeat="val in ctrl.values" where values are hardcoded array in the controller. Since My json has "Status" as on of the key. I want my dropdown to bind to status from the Json not the hard coded Values array. Hope its clear now

Comment: is this doable?

Comment: Are you asking if the values array can be initialized with data from the peoples array?

Comment: Yes. The above dropdown is being initialized from the values array (these are hardcoded values of available and not available). What I want is the values of dropdown should depend upon the People array (which is the json I get from my api). So if my people array has 2 values (available and not available) dropdown should show 2 values. If it has 3 values (avaliable, not available & pending). It should show these values. And the key from the json/arrray to bind is the "Status".

Comment: You can simply use a javascript map to create the values array, like this vm.values = [...new Set( vm.people.map(obj => ({value: obj.status}))) ];  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Got it now. Will implement in my app and post if any issues. Thanks for the help.